# Tomar foto en automático desde sitio web desde el mi móvil

Tags: javascript, mysql, html5, script

Hola a Todos estoy hacien una funcion que sera exclusiva para dispositivios movil desde una web, quisiera ver quien me puede ayudar tengo el codigo siguiente el cual explico lo que hace

```
<img id="photo" class="photo">
```

este elemento lo tengo para ahi mostrar la foto que tomo

```
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" id="camera" />
```

con este invoco que cuando hagan clic en el boton llame a la camara para tomar foto, y obio asi no pueden subirla de la galeria y el scrpipt de abajo solo es el que nos ayuda a mostrar la foto en el elemento img

```
        <script language="JavaScript">
                        const photo = document.querySelector('#photo');
                        const camera = document.querySelector('#camera');
                        camera.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
                        photo.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
                        });
        </script>
```

Ahora bien una vez explicado lo que estoy haciendo, lo que quiero es cuando den clic en el boton para invocar la camara usar el temporalizador para que a los 2 segundos tome la foto sin presionar el boton de tomado, o en su defecto sin temporalizador que la tome directo, y que no me pida como palomita de validacion si no que la guarde directamente que no tenga que seleccionar entre la "tache" o la "palomita" para despues esa imagen junto con otro dato un texto plano cualquiera lo guarde en una base de datos que tengo, alguien podria darme una pequeña asesoria ?

Comment: Cuál es el error?

Comment: [Aquí](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/capturing-images?hl=es#obtener_un_resumen_desde_la_c%C3%A1mara) mencionan como usar `<video>` y `<canvas>` para capturar una imagen.